How to fix: No module named 'notebook', to run Turtle via mobilechelonian?
Here is my code:
from mobilechelonian import Turtle

t = Turtle()
t = t.forward(100)

In my Python environment (VS Code terminal), the following error occurs every time when my code runs. The code is very simple in 3 lines. Why does this error occur?
PS C:\Users\master\Desktop\PythonWorkSpace> > & C:/Python311/python.exe c:/Users/master/Desktop/PythonWorkSpace/Statitics_week2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\master\Desktop\PythonWorkSpace\Statitics_week2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mobilechelonian import Turtle
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mobilechelonian\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>       
    from notebook import nbextensions 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook'

I did my best to correct this problem. I tried reinstalling (jupyter, notebook, mobilechelonian)

Which version of notebook are you running? Perhaps try running pip uninstall notebook and then pip install --upgrade notebook==7.2.2

You could use pip list in the current environment to check whether the python package has been installed. You could also use shortcuts Ctrl+Shift+P and type Python: Select Interpreter to choose the python interpreter which you installed the python package, then choose the jupyter kernel in the jupyter-notebook.

@Wayne Comments are for minor or transient information. There is a good reason their length is limited.

Alternative option to run Turtle via mobilechelonian:
I'd suggest it is much easier at this time to run Turtle via mobilechelonian in Jupyter sessions running on remote virtual machines that have been specified to have the software needed.
Go to here and click 'launch binder'. (Or just click here to get started with a session launch directly.)
Turtle will work in the temporary session that comes up. If you make anything useful download it so you can use the notebook or code again later in a fresh session started the same way.
Turtle will work in the temporary session that comes up.
If you make anything useful, download it so you can use the notebook or code again later in a fresh session started the same way.
Currently, my fork of mobilechelonian works to launch. Eventually it should work with MyBinder-served launches using based on the main repo at https://github.com/takluyver/mobilechelonian/ because the developer has asked me to submit a pull request to fix this and it is pending right now. I'll try to update the text and links here when that happens, so it is referencing only the main mobilechelonian repository.

Details
The original title of this post was 'Python Anaconda', and so I assume the OP is using the Anaconda Distribution here.
Currently, the default Anaconda Distribution now includes current JupyterLab and Jupyter Notebook 7+.  Nbextensions don't work the same way in Notebook 7+ and aren't included even, and so all that may explain from notebook import nbextensions. Along these lines is that this says it doesn't work in JupyterLab. Current Notebook 7+ is built on JupyterLab components and so if it doesn't work in JupyterLab, it doesn't work in Jupyter Notebook 7+.
NbClassic includes the old Nbextensions system. And so making an environment and installing that and getting it working in the environment where you want to run from mobilechelonian import Turtle. That would be the most direct route to set up your machine to make this work.
However, that is a lot to do (you may get a sense of that from my comments here and this issues post & exchange) and will get more difficult as time goes on and NbClassic continues to become more outdated.
As a workaround for now, I'm suggesting using MyBinder to get sessions running NbClassic where Turle running via mobilechelonian will work.
Since OP also mentioned Python in a terminal, I'll point out that you can also run Python directly in a terminal in those sessions.  You can use Turtle via mobilechelonian in Python by opening a terminal in the sessions and running on the command line python to open a Python console. I don't know what will happen with the output though since it needs graphics and so Jupyter would be easier.
I'll add that this is the current state of things. If this issue about it working in JupyterLab were to get addressed, then things would change, and it wouldn't be tied to old Jupyter tech and old ipywidgets.
